# mySQL WorkBench Scripting shell unresponsive

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench ver 8.0 CE with MariaDB ver 10.1.3 on Windows 10.
When I click on Scripting -> Scripting Shell I get a console screen showing things like
Registered 183 GRT classes
Registered 37 modules (from 35 files)
..
..
Type ? For help
Python Shell initialized
Ready.

However, this screen does not allow me to input any text and seems to be in a hung state. I don't have python installed on this machine, could this be a problem or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the "Scripting Shell" is aimed at MySQL 8.0, and won't work with any version of MariaDB yet.  Consider using an older version of Workbench or phpmyadmin or something else.

Comment: I'm a new user to the workbench and mainly interested in manipulating the models through python so I guess I could use the scripts which seem to execute through the other tab. So, if the shell is to query the database tables etc. then I could forego for the moment.